Appropriate applications for the as_strided function
I am practicing on figuring out how to use the as_strided function in numpy. I began with the following example of my own where I generate 5 images of 3 x 3 where each image is full of 1s, the next full of 2s, and so on till 5. If I want convert the (5,3,3) volume to place all images into a single row, I can do the following which works:
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

array_3d = np.empty((5, 3, 3))

for i in range(5):
    array_3d[i] = np.full((3, 3), i+1)

print(array_3d.itemsize)

array_2d = as_strided(array_3d, shape=(5, 9), strides=(8*9, 8))

print(array_2d)

This outputs the following:
8
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
 [3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4.]
 [5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]]

Now I wanted to try harder example of placing the (3, 3) images side by side in the following manner using the as_strided function:
[[1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3. 4. 4. 4. 5. 5. 5.]
 [1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3. 4. 4. 4. 5. 5. 5.]
 [1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3. 4. 4. 4. 5. 5. 5.]]

However, I cannot think of a way to do this just using the as_strided function. So I am wondering if this is just not possible only with the as_strided function and how can I know when it is appropriate to use the as_strided function apart from sliding window operations.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html is a safer and easier to use wrapper. Both functions can be found in other SO questions and answers.  An obvious use in sliding windiw mean (or other summary)

Note that in your second example, it is 3x4 images that you put side by side, not 3x3 images. You have 12 occurrences of each numbers, that is 60 numbers all together, when there are only 45 numbers in the initial array_3d. Is this what you really want?

its 3x3, it was a typo, i fixed it up now

Assuming that you really, in reality, want a 3x15 array containing 9 "1", 9 "2", ...
And making the same mistake as you did for your first example
st1,st2,st3=array_3d.strides
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(array_3d, shape=(3,15), strides=(st3,st2))

It works. But under the same abusive assumption that you made for you first example: under the assumption that array_3d data are consecutive. That is that strides of array_3d are (8*9, 8*3, 8) (the strides of a 3d array of shape (*,3,3) of contiguous data, with data size being 8 bytes).
array_3d = np.empty((5, 3, 3))
for i in range(5):
    array_3d[i] = np.full((3, 3), i+1)
# Or np.repeat(np.arange(1,6),9).reshape(5,3,3)
st1,st2,st3=array_3d.strides # Following your method, I could have used 8 as st3, and 8*3 for st2. 
      # But I prefer this way, that works better when array_3d is not contiguous
      # even if (see later) it is not sufficient here
as_strided(array_3d, shape=(3,15), strides=(st3,st2))

⇒
array([[1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 4., 4., 4., 5., 5., 5.],
       [1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 4., 4., 4., 5., 5., 5.],
       [1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 4., 4., 4., 5., 5., 5.]])

But if data are not contiguous, that is if array_3d[x,y+1,0] is not immediately after array_3d[x,y,2], then both your code and mine do not work.
And there could be plenty of reason why it could not be so. For a start, because that array_3d could also be the result of another as_strided.
Or some other simpler operations. Such as reshape, transpose, or even simple subarray.
For example, imagine that, instead of my np.repeat trick to replace your for loop to construct array_3d, I suggested that other trick
array_3d = np.block([np.arange(1,6)]*9).reshape(3,3,5).T

array_3d is
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3]],

       [[4, 4, 4],
        [4, 4, 4],
        [4, 4, 4]],

       [[5, 5, 5],
        [5, 5, 5],
        [5, 5, 5]]])

like yours, or like the np.repeat one.
But its strides are (8,40,120)
So your code gives, for the first example
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])

And even with my more flexible way (computing strides of target with actual strides of array_3d, not assumed strides as if array_3d were contiguous)
array([[                  1,                   1,                   1,
                       8961, 4426024058838412064, 2314885530453962528,
        2336916743122085218, 8367723430002978409, 8318818597302461550],
       [                  2,                   2,                   2,
                          1, 2842441403096198183, 7307499879225255280,
        6933981515683226426, 7810489018405119336, 2338623232261300325],
       [                  3,                   3,                   3,
                   11162752, 7883868307246424108, 8028827851415429235,
        7958530579755660158, 7575167200708226665, 2334386829830418017],
       [                  4,                   4,                   4,
                       8910, 7310589477035273328, 8386668381597627251,
        7955973979015377710, 8390317583586653294, 7020095223739741549],
       [                  5,                   5,                   5,
                         -1, 8243122375611719780, 7236828443234430825,
        2332938645024170341, 8241988044566393376, 8030041785346585459]])

(I know, it looks even worse. But at least I got the first 3 numbers of each line correct. The fact that the other are rubish comes from the fact that the 4th 5 is not separated from the 3rd by the same amount of memory than the 3rd is separated by the 2nd. Which is the false assumption your are doing).
Likewise for the 2nd example with my code.
I could have done same demonstration for yet simpler array_3d. For example if you built a (5,4,4) big_array_3d using your method, and then extract a (5,3,3) from it array_3d = big_array_3d[:,:3,:3]. It's not really a hacker convoluted trick, is it? That is a quite usual piece of code. And yet, array_3d is not a contiguous bunch of data.
So, point is, if you start playing with strides, and therefore construct array whose strides are not the one of a plain old contiguous "C" order array, you should be the 1st one aware that not all arrays are made of contiguous data, and the 1st one to avoid assuming they are.
An array in numpy is a bunch of data with a type, and a shape and some strides telling how to translate a [i1,i2,i3,...] index into one of the data. Using formula array[i1,i2,i3,...,ik] is the dtype found at address baseAddress + i1*stride1 + i2*stride2 + i3*stride3 + ... + ik*stridek.
as_strided allows you to take advantage of the fact that you understand that, to alter shape and strides of an array to show different indexing rules (like transpose does. Or, depending on conditions, reshape, indexing, moveaxis, ... as_strided is just the most generic version of those functions that do not change the data, only the shape and strides)
But that means that to be able to do a trick with as_strided, you need to find what set of strides make baseAddress+i1*stride1+i2*stride2+...+ik*stridek be what you want view[i1,i2,...,ik] to be. Which means that such strides must exist. And it is not always the case. Not any rearrangement of the data can be expressed as a linear indexing formula 'α.i1+β.i2+...' (α, β, ... being the strides)

Your 'rubish' values come from 'sampling' outside the original data_base.  That's one of dangers of using as_strided.  With the wrong mix of shape and strides it can see rubish values.  slding_window_view was added, in part, to prevent this.  It's docs have some good application notes.

Making a slightly different array - without the fill/repeat so we can tell how the (3,3) arrays are ordered:
In [128]: array_3d = np.empty((4, 3, 3))
     ...: for i in range(4):
     ...:     array_3d[i] = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)+i*10
     ...:     

In [129]: array_3d
Out[129]: 
array([[[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
        [ 6.,  7.,  8.]],

       [[10., 11., 12.],
        [13., 14., 15.],
        [16., 17., 18.]],

       [[20., 21., 22.],
        [23., 24., 25.],
        [26., 27., 28.]],

       [[30., 31., 32.],
        [33., 34., 35.],
        [36., 37., 38.]]])

We can get your first layout with a simple reshape:
In [130]: array_3d.reshape(4,-1)
Out[130]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.],
       [10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18.],
       [20., 21., 22., 23., 24., 25., 26., 27., 28.],
       [30., 31., 32., 33., 34., 35., 36., 37., 38.]])

Add in a transpose, we can join your blocks:
In [131]: array_3d.transpose(1,0,2).reshape(3,-1)
Out[131]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2., 10., 11., 12., 20., 21., 22., 30., 31., 32.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5., 13., 14., 15., 23., 24., 25., 33., 34., 35.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8., 16., 17., 18., 26., 27., 28., 36., 37., 38.]])

And with a different transpose, layout the blocks differently.  This distinction is lost when the blocks are 'filled':
In [132]: array_3d.transpose(2,0,1).reshape(3,-1)
Out[132]: 
array([[ 0.,  3.,  6., 10., 13., 16., 20., 23., 26., 30., 33., 36.],
       [ 1.,  4.,  7., 11., 14., 17., 21., 24., 27., 31., 34., 37.],
       [ 2.,  5.,  8., 12., 15., 18., 22., 25., 28., 32., 35., 38.]])

[132] is actually a view of array_3d (which we can varify by checking its .base).
[131] is also a view, but of a (3,4,3) base, the transpose.  Reshape after a transpose often involves some sort of copy.
We can also get the [131] layout with concatenate:
In [143]: np.concatenate(array_3d, axis=1)
Out[143]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2., 10., 11., 12., 20., 21., 22., 30., 31., 32.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5., 13., 14., 15., 23., 24., 25., 33., 34., 35.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8., 16., 17., 18., 26., 27., 28., 36., 37., 38.]])

as_strided
as_strided is most often used to break an array into smaller pieces, rather than to reduce dimensions.  np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view is a 'safer' and easier to used version.  Among other things it prevents us from sampling outside the original data_buffer.
That said, as_strided can be used to get 2d layouts.
As you found the simple reshape can be replicated with:
In [145]: np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(array_3d,shape=(4,9), strides=(9*8,8))
Out[145]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.],
       [10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18.],
       [20., 21., 22., 23., 24., 25., 26., 27., 28.],
       [30., 31., 32., 33., 34., 35., 36., 37., 38.]])

ANd by using different strides we get [132]:
In [149]: np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(array_3d,shape=(3,12), strides=(8,3*8))
Out[149]: 
array([[ 0.,  3.,  6., 10., 13., 16., 20., 23., 26., 30., 33., 36.],
       [ 1.,  4.,  7., 11., 14., 17., 21., 24., 27., 31., 34., 37.],
       [ 2.,  5.,  8., 12., 15., 18., 22., 25., 28., 32., 35., 38.]])

Note how the consecutive numbers, [0,1,2,3...] are ordered down the columns, order='F'.  That's typical where trailing strides are larger.
I don't think the [131] layout can be achieved with as_strided.  As I noted it isn't a view of the original array.
creating (3,3) windows
To illustrate how as_strided can be used to break an array into small blocks, we can use sliding_window_view to construct (3,3) blocks from the [131] 2d array:
In [152]: np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(_131,(3,3)).shape
Out[152]: (1, 10, 3, 3)

You can print it to see how those blocks 'overlap/sliding), but by taking every 3rd block, we recover the original 3d array:
In [153]: np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(_131,(3,3))[0,:3]
Out[153]: 
array([[[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
        [ 6.,  7.,  8.]],

       [[ 1.,  2., 10.],
        [ 4.,  5., 13.],
        [ 7.,  8., 16.]],

       [[ 2., 10., 11.],
        [ 5., 13., 14.],
        [ 8., 16., 17.]]])

And doing the same for [132], we the original, but with transposed blocks:
In [154]: np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(_132,(3,3))[0,:3]
Out[154]: 
array([[[ 0.,  3.,  6.],
        [ 1.,  4.,  7.],
        [ 2.,  5.,  8.]],

       [[ 3.,  6., 10.],
        [ 4.,  7., 11.],
        [ 5.,  8., 12.]],

       [[ 6., 10., 13.],
        [ 7., 11., 14.],
        [ 8., 12., 15.]]])

sliding_window_view docs has some good usage examples and cautions.
fill/repeat
The fill/repeat constuction can be done with as_strided.
Start with a simple 1d array:
In [163]: arr = np.arange(4)

We can use another stride_tricks function to 'replicate' the values:
In [164]: np.broadcast_to(arr,(3,3,4))
Out[164]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3]]])

and then transpose to get the same sort of pattern you created:
In [165]: np.broadcast_to(arr,(3,3,4)).transpose(2,0,1)
Out[165]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3]]])

Note the strides of this array:
In [166]: np.broadcast_to(arr,(3,3,4)).transpose(2,0,1).strides
Out[166]: (4, 0, 0)

We can produce the same thing with as_strided:
In [167]: np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr,(4,3,3),(4,0,0))
Out[167]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3]]])

broadcast_to uses another tool, nditer to achieve this.  I suspect they do this to avoid some writeabilty issues.
We don't often need to use broadcast_to; simply adding dimensions is enough (plus the rules of broadcasting):
In [173]: arr[:,None,None]
Out[173]: 
array([[[100]],

       [[100]],

       [[100]],

       [[100]]])

In [174]: _.strides
Out[174]: (4, 0, 0) 

This has the same stides, but a (4,1,1) shape.

import numpy as np

# Create the 3D array (5 images of size 3x3)
array_3d = np.empty((5, 3, 3))
for i in range(5):
    array_3d[i] = np.full((3, 3), i+1)

# Print the original 3D array
print("Original 3D array:")
print(array_3d)
'''
Output:
[[[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 [[2. 2. 2.]
  [2. 2. 2.]
  [2. 2. 2.]]

 [[3. 3. 3.]
  [3. 3. 3.]
  [3. 3. 3.]]

 [[4. 4. 4.]
  [4. 4. 4.]
  [4. 4. 4.]]

 [[5. 5. 5.]
  [5. 5. 5.]
  [5. 5. 5.]]]
'''
print("Shape of the 3D array:", array_3d.shape)  # Output: (5, 3, 3)

# Step 1: Reshape the 3D array into a 2D array where each 3x3 image is flattened into a single row
flattened_2d = array_3d.reshape(5, 3 * 3)
print("Flattened 2D array:")
print(flattened_2d)
'''
Output:
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
 [3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4.]
 [5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]]
'''

# Step 2: Transpose the 2D array to switch rows and columns
transposed_2d = flattened_2d.T
print("Transposed 2D array:")
print(transposed_2d)
'''
Output:
[[1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
 [1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
 [1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
 [1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
 [1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
 [1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
 [1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
 [1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
 [1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]]
'''

# Step 3: Reshape the transposed array to arrange the images side by side
side_by_side_2d = transposed_2d.reshape(3, 5 * 3)
print("Final 2D array with images side by side:")
print(side_by_side_2d)
'''
Output:
[[1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
 [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
 [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]]
'''

